# Can one sell his BAR-METZRA rights to a non-neighbor?

Tags: halacha, real-estate

Can one sell his [BAR_METZRA](http://www.etzion.org.il/en/bar-metzra-%D6%A0first-right-purchase-neighbor) rights to a non-neighbor?

Comment: Gemara in BB tells about the middas sdom problem

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned here many a time, Wikipedia is not considered a good source for accuracy in Torah related information. But just as a starting platform [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%90) cites a dispute among the *Rishonim* whether Bar-Metzra is a right of the neighbor, or only an obligation on the seller, or on a non neighboring buyer.

The answer to the question may be dependent on this dispute. If Bar-Metzra is only an obligation on the seller, or on a non neighboring buyer, then the neighbor has no "rights" to sell. Only if we say that Bar-Metzra is a right of the neighbor, then there may be a possibility that he may be able to sell this right.

[Answer inspired by comment from DAVID KENNER]

Comment: Hmm, it would be nice and more credible to have a real source though other than Wikipedia. But it's a good start for sure.